# What does \1 (backslash 1) do in Ruby strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

[ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections#human](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-human) uses a `\1` in the example:

```
human /_cnt$/i, '\1_count'
```

As far as I can tell, that's actually adding a `\u0001` character to the string, and it seems to still work if I just use `'_count'`. Can anyone tell me what the `\1` is actually supposed to be doing?

Comment: Nothing, it's just a literal backslash character followed by a `1` character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that under the hood, they are passing that string to `gsub` or something similar. In a `gsub` replacement string, `'\1'` has a special meaning -- it refers to whatever the first capturing group in the regex argument matched.

For example, try:

```
 "a short sentence".gsub(/([aeiou])/, '\1\1')
```

If you use `"\1"`, now that is a completely different thing. That is a `\u001` character. (Escapes work differently in single-quoted and double-quoted Ruby strings.)

Probably the reason why omitting the `\1` doesn't seem to change anything in the example you gave, is because there is no capturing group in the regex.

Comment: Ok, so maybe they intended this as a `human /(.*)_cnt$/i, '\1_count'` which works correctly using the `\1`. And indeed, when I implemented this in my inflections, I used double quotes (and didn't realize the difference when testing). Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If you came across this like me and were wondering why you were getting u001's in your output even when formatted like the above, make sure that your replacement string is SINGLE quoted. Double quotes will actually generate an escape character.